# Compilation GWT with jdk17

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm trying to migrate gwt application from java 1.8 to 17 (java source remains in 1.8).

I'm using gwt-maven-plugin version 2.9.0. Compilation with open JDK 17 based on logs looks ok, there are no errors, comparing to compilation with JDK1.8 debug logs look the same.
All files (such css, images, js, rpc.log, gwt.log and so on) are based on log created.

But when compilaiton is finished, module directory in war remains empty, there is just directory structure but no files (e.g. gwt.rpc, resources, cache.js,nocache.js... are missing).

In log is mentioned "Compile of permutations succeeded .... Linking succeeded". Content of directory gwt-unitCache looks also ok.

Do you have some idea why that happens?

Thanks a lot!

Part of log:

```
Compiling 2 permutations
16:19:20 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Creating worker permutation 0 of 2
16:19:20 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Creating worker permutation 1 of 2
16:19:20 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Creating PermutationWorkerFactory instances
16:19:20 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
16:19:29 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Compiling permutation 1...
16:23:17 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Splitting JavaScript for incremental download
16:23:18 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Splitting JavaScript for incremental download
16:23:21 [Thread-95] [INFO]          Fixed up load-order dependencies for instance methods by moving 0 types to fragment 0, out of 31425
....
16:25:26 [Thread-95] [INFO]          Done
16:25:26 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Permutation took 365658 ms
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO]          Done
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Permutation took 366193 ms
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Successfully compiled permutation
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO]       Successfully compiled permutation
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 2112.388s
16:25:27 [Thread-95] [INFO] Linking into D:\zzz\applications\xxx\target\xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT\yyyyy
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one workaround that worked -> set different output directory for plugin gwt-maven-plugin with parameter webappDirectory, e.g. d:\output

Then output if generated correctly. Then copy content back to target war directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your compilation output you should see the directory that the GWT compiler is storing the GWT application files.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.2:compile (default) @ Foo ---
[INFO] Compiling module com.me.Foo
[INFO] Linking into /home/.../Foo/target/Foo-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT/Foo
[INFO]    Link succeeded
```

If that directory is empty, something very odd is happening; try deleting the target directory and try compiling again.

Comment: Target is always cleaned before compilation. There is also message "Link succeeded", but there is just directory structure created in module directory. The same happens on windows and Jenkins (Linux).

Comment: so the directory mentioned in the output "[INFO] Linking into ...." has no files?

Comment: Maybe share the build log, pom contents? It sure doesn't sound like GWT or the gwt plugin for maven is causing this...

Comment: I tried to change output directory in gwt-maven-plugin - parameter <webappDirectory>, with  different directory it works. Looks there is some problem with direct writing into module target directory (xxx\target\xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT\ModuleName)